# How to define routes with a custom protocol/scheme with node.js?

Tags: node.js, http, protocols

I scrapped the internet but did not find any good resource on how to create routes with a custom scheme (my-app://) with node.js.

Strictly speaking, it would not really be custom protocol, it would be http but served with another scheme.

How can I do that?

I can install any npm packages.

Answer (score 1):

If it is HTTP then even though some other client application is using another scheme to connect, you will still get it as HTTP on the server side.

In fact, in the HTTP protocol you don't get the protocol scheme in the request. You get the host (hostname and port) in the Host heared and yu get the path (with query string but no fragment part) in the GET lite of the request (or POST etc.). At no point the client sends any indication of what protocol does it use, unless it's a request to a forward proxy server (but not if it's a reverse proxy).

It is your server that assumes which protocol scheme is used because it knows what protocol it speaks with on a given port. In the case that you describe of a client that uses some other protocol name in the URL but connects to your server using HTTP, your server will only need to know HTTP and the routes doesn't usually include the protocol anyway, maybe unless it's Diet.js but even then it's used in the listen argument, not in the routes.

This is an example HTTP request:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:3344
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Ubuntu Chromium/53.0.2785.143 Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8,pl;q=0.6
```

The only place where it has "HTTP" is the first line defining the version of the protocol so that the client could understand the headers properly and this you would need to keep anyway so that your server could work if you want to use the built in `http` module or any framework in Node. If you changed that then you will have to write your own parser of the protocol.